# Footer View won't stick to bottom of UITableView, but overlaps table instead (auto-layout issue)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

For some reason, my footer overlaps the table rather than acting as a footer, to the bottom. This is most likely an auto-layout

```
var coreView = UIView() //This is the footer
var postBody = UILabel() //This is the label, which will determine the height of the footer.

let nib = UINib(nibName: "MessagesTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    let 

nibSimple = UINib(nibName: "SimpleMessagesTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
self.tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MessagesTableViewCell")
self.tableView.registerNib(nibSimple, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SimpleMessagesTableViewCell")
self.tableView.dataSource = self
self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(hex: 0xf5f5f5)
self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
self.tableView.clipsToBounds = true
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
self.tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .OnDrag


    coreView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

    //Create Label and add it to the footer
    postBody.text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
    postBody.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 16.0)
    postBody.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
    postBody.numberOfLines = 0
    postBody.backgroundColor = FlatLime()
    coreView.addSubview(postBody)

    //Enable constraints for footer and label
    postBody.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    coreView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    //Add constraints to the footer and post body
    let postBodyLeadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: postBody, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: coreView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    postBodyLeadingConstraint.active = true

    let postBodyTrailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: postBody, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: coreView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    postBodyTrailingConstraint.active = true

    let postBodyTopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: postBody, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: coreView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    postBodyTopConstraint.active = true

    let postBodyBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: postBody, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: coreView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    postBodyBottomConstraint.active = true

    postBody.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = screenWidth
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = coreView
```

As you can see, the autolayout works to determine the height of the footer view (based on the label's height).
However, this is the result.  The footer "overlaps" the table, even though I set it as the footer view int the last line.

Also: does anyone know why there is a white blank space to the right of the coreView?

[image: footer overlaps table]

Answer (score 0):

why not try to change UITableViewStyle to Group, I think it would worked.

Answer (score 0):

Layout postBody with top, leading and width constraints may solve the problem.